# Integrating $\int _0^1\sqrt{9\sin^2(x)+9\cos^2(x)+16}\ \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

What I'm trying to do is find the arc length of $r(x) = \langle 3\cos(x),4x,3\sin(x)\rangle$ when $0\le x\le 1$.
After I derived the vector and found the magnitude of that derived vector, I came up with $$\int_0^1\sqrt{9\sin^2(x)+9\cos^2(x)+16}\ \mathrm dx$$
as the solution. Now I have to integrate it and I'm not so sure where to begin because I haven't seen a problem like this before.

Comment: t? Ummmmmmm...what are you integrating with respect to ?

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be x

Comment: Are you sure that should be $-9sin^2(x)$? Did you square a negative term to get that?

Comment: It's supposed to be positive. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @igknighton correct your title too :)

Comment: Do you know the identity $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x =1$ ? , which would mean that $9\sin^2 x + 9\cos^2 x = 9(\sin^2 x+ \cos^2 x)=9(1)$

Comment: Yes, I do. I think I can factor out the nine and then add 9 and 16 to get sqrt(25) = 5. Then I integrate that to get 5t. Is the answer 5?

Comment: @igknighton yes 5x is the answer. I dont know why you keep typing t instead of x

Comment: @Lolman In the vector r(t), its 4x. I have to derive that to get 4. Then I square that to get 16. I think 16x^2 is right.

Comment: @igknighton No, $4^2 = 16$ (without any $x$) is correct.

Comment: @AlexR that was a typo. I mean to put "I don't think"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**
$\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x = 1$ due to Pythagoras, so the question is
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{25}\ \mathrm dx = ?$$

---

Since there has been a discussion if the integral was actually correct (wich it was), here is the long answer:
$$r(x) = \langle 3\cos x, 4x, 3\sin x\rangle\\
\nabla r(x) = \langle -3\sin x, 4, 3\cos x\rangle$$
Now the [arc length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Lengths_of_curves) is defined by
$$L_a^b (r) := \int_a^b \| \nabla r(x) \|_2\ \mathrm dx$$
Note that $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \ldots}$ so
$$\|\nabla r(x)\|_2 = \sqrt{(-3\sin x)^2 + 4^2 + (3\cos x)^2} = \sqrt{9 (\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x) + 16} = \sqrt{25} = 5$$
Where we used Pythagoras ($\sin^2 x +\cos^2 x = 1$ for all $x$). Thus
$$L_0^1 (r) = \int_0^1 5\ \mathrm dx = 5$$

Comment: @DanielV Look up the definition of arc length, please. I've posted a [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059562/integrating-int-01-sqrt9-sin2x9-cos2x16-mathrm-dx/1059584?noredirect=1#comment2156813_1059582) with it if this suffices for you.

Comment: You are correct, I've deleted, thank you~~

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{9\sin^2 x+ 9\cos^2 x+ 16} dx=\int_0^1 \sqrt{9(\color{Crimson}{\sin^2x+\cos^2x})+16}dx$$

> $$\color{Crimson}{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}=1$$

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{9(\color{Crimson}{\sin^2x+\cos^2x})+16}dx=\int_0^1 \sqrt{9\cdot1+16} dx$$

$$=\int_0^1 \sqrt{25} dx$$

*From the comment section you seemed uncertain if $5x$ is **correct**, and  you had to double check with me, which is not necessary  if you have a sound mastery on the following:*

$$\int_a^b x^{\color{blue}{n}}dx=\left[\frac{ x^{\color{blue}{n+1}}}{\color{blue}{n+1}}\right]_a^b$$

---

And you  should know that 1 can be written as:

$$1=x^0$$

*And what I said can be applied*

---

$$\int_0^1 5x^{\color{blue}{0}}dx=\Large{\left[5 \frac{x^{\color{blue}{0+1}}}{\color{blue}{0+1}}\right]_0^1}$$

$$= \left[5x\right]_0^1=5\cdot1-5\cdot0$$

Comment: `\cdot` is your best friend for multiplication ;)

Comment: @AlexR Thanks :) yep

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{0}^{1}(9sin^{2}(x)+9cos^{3}(x)+16)^{\frac{1}{2}} dx= \int_{0}^{1}(9(1-cos^{2}(x))+9cos^{2}(x)+16)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx = \int_{0}^{1}(25)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx = 5$

Comment: Comment deleted.  Sorry.

Comment: @Louis What?${}$

Comment: Derive $4x$. And then square it.

Comment: @Louis The arc length of a curve parameterised by $(t, r(t))$ on $[a,b]$ is given by
$$L_a^b(r) = \int_a^b \| \nabla r(t) \|_2\ \mathrm dt$$
Here $$\nabla r(x) = \langle -3\sin x, 4, 3\cos x\rangle$$

Answer (score -1):

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{9\sin(x)^2+16\cos(x)^2+16}\,\, dx \\
\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{9(\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2)+16}\,\,dx  \\
\left[\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1\right] \\
\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{9+16}\,\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{25}\,\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}5\,\,dx = 5*(1-0) = 5
$$

Comment: Is there any apparent reason why one would post the exact same answer as others before without any changes other than formatting?

Comment: @AlexR A convergence (hahaha) of solutions?